# SQL Server slow query when adding third join, no matter what that join is

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL query as follows - pretty straight forward.

```
SELECT 
    p.ProgressClaimID, 
    min(p.ClaimDate) as ClaimDate, 
    min(p.PClaimValue) as PClaimValue, 
    sum(d.total) as TotalDaycost, 
    sum(i.amount) as TotalInvoice,
    sum(round(pcd.QtyClaimed * pcd.SellRate,2)) as SellClaim
FROM 
    (ProgressClaim as p 
LEFT JOIN
    ProgressClaimDetail as pcd ON p.ProgressClaimID = pcd.ProgressClaimID) 
LEFT JOIN
    [DayCost] as d ON p.ProgressClaimID = d.ReportPeriod 
LEFT JOIN
    Invoice as i ON p.ProgressClaimID = i.ReportPeriod 
WHERE
    p.projectID = 4
GROUP BY
    p.ProgressClaimID
```

But it is running very slowly (a couple of seconds) with very few rows (a few hundred at most) in SQL Server 2014. To make it more strange, this query runs as expected (pretty much instant) on my identical data on a SQL Server CE database.

In the SQL Server install, if I take out any join - it runs as expected with the remaining 3 tables - regardless of which one is removed.

I have checked FK, indexes etc. Nothing seems obvious. Any pointers appreciated.

***Edit
Execution plan at http://textuploader.com/5eurg (XML)

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: You might want to include the output from `EXPLAIN`, as I'm sure you would be asked for this anyway.

Comment: Try to check the execution plan of the query. it will tell you which part of the query./join is slower and probably why.

Comment: Have you checked the fragmentation of the indexes ?

Comment: Checked fragmentation - nothing to see there. Added execution plans

Comment: Please post the statistics of the actual execution plan (actual number of rows, estimated number of rows...). Since you are on MSSQL 2014 you should try LiveQueryStatistics to figure out where's the query spending most of the time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in my query design. This is what happens when you have been writing SQL for a while. Essentially the query takes a long time because each left join makes subsequent multiple copies of the rows which are then summed - there is a lot of computation going on by the third join.

I rewrote my query to do what I meant it to do and it is all good.

Embarassing mistake - here it is for the curious

```
SELECT p.ProgressClaimID, p.ClaimDate, p.PClaimValue,
pcd.pcdTotal,
d.TotalDaycost,
i.TotalInvoice
FROM ProgressClaim as p 
left join (select ProgressClaimID, sum(round(QtyClaimed * SellRate,2)) as pcdTotal from ProgressClaimDetail group by ProgressClaimID) as pcd on p.ProgressClaimID=pcd.ProgressClaimID
left join (select ReportPeriod, sum(total) as TotalDaycost from DayCost group by ReportPeriod) as d on p.ProgressClaimID= d.ReportPeriod 
left join (select ReportPeriod, sum(amount) as TotalInvoice from Invoice group by ReportPeriod) as i on p.ProgressClaimID= i.ReportPeriod 
where p.projectID=4
```